# I need to compare values of two different loops in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My xml file looks like this-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
    <old>
    <Address>
        <code>1</code>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <code>2</code>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <code>3</code>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <code>4</code>
    </Address>
    </old>
    <new>
    <Address>
        <code>1</code>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <code>2</code>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <code>5</code>
    </Address>
    </new>
    </root>
```

and I need to compare old/Address/code to new/Address/code and vice-versa. If the values match I need to concat it otherwise print it as it is.
So the final output will be:

```
    <City>
    <countryCode>1122345</countryCode>
    </City>
```

Comment: xslt 1.0 or 2.0

Comment: @Rupesh I need to implement in xslt 1.0

Answer (score 0):

In **xslt 2.0** you can try this

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <City>
        <countryCode>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="deep-equal(old/*, new/*)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="old//code"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//code">
                        <xsl:sort select="."/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </countryCode>
    </City>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it simple (and presumed that original order of `Address/old` is not important), forget about comparing, instead just concatenate all `code` from `Address/old` and `Address/new` and sort them:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <City>
        <countryCode>
            <xsl:for-each select="(old|new)/Address/code">
                <!-- or, if you like it really dirty: //code -->
                <xsl:sort/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </countryCode>
    </City>
</xsl:template>
```

This will produce the desired result from the given example and works in XSLT 1.0.